# How do I create a shell-extension / file container dll like winzip?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, shell-extensions, winzip

Ok so I need to make a file container program or namespace extension similar to that of winzip or winrar.

Now I don't need the files to be compressed or encrypted or anything special like that.

What I need is to create a dll that works off an extension such as .xyz (i know how to register all this into the registry so thats not a problem), and when clicked on will open all the files in the "container" in a window like winzip does.

What I have currently is I have a program that adds all the files I what into a big file with an extension (like .xyz). But what I have no idea how to do is how to make it so when I click or open this new file that they will open up in a window (filesystem broswer? or something? like winzip does) so that I can view all the files that are in this "container".

can someone point me in the right direction on this or how to do it, right now I'm stumped.

I should also mention I'm working in c#.net

Comment: So it's not that you want to open your custom file in a custom window, you want to have the normal windows file explorer understand what your file is so you can navigate it like you would a regular zip file, is that right?

Comment: I believe so. what I want is to "package" them up and then have them open in a window just like a zip file. 

However, the files in them are "wrapped" in my custom data. So when dragging and dropping the files in and out of this window they will need to get wrapped / unwrapped in this data.

like when you drag a file in and out a zip folder it gets compressed/uncompressed.

Comment: Do you want them to display in a custom window created by you? Or do you want them to display in a standard Explorer window?

Comment: a standard window will be fine :)

Comment: Displaying them in a custom window is easy, just write a standalone application and register it as the handler. Displaying them in a standard Explorer window is very hard because that requires you to write a shell namespace extension, which cannot be done from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8063/The-Mini-Shell-Extension-Framework-Part-I

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9421/The-Mini-Shell-extension-Framework-Part-II

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11674/The-Mini-Shell-Extension-Framework-Part-III

Exactly you want, but in c++ ;-)
Doing shell exts in C Sharp is painful.